# My servlet throws exception ResourceClosed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence

My servlet is contacted simultaneously by three devices that read the result. 
A strange thing happens: the first device displays the result, often the second, while the third device receives 500 internal server error, because the exception is thrown *org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: This TransactionCoordinator has been closed* (shown below after the code ). 
So, I understand that the session is started with the database is shared by the three devices and when one of them ends up operations and closes the session after the devices will shut. Why does this happen? I want a dedicated session for each tutor.

```
@WebServlet("/UpdateTutor")
public class UpdateTutor extends HttpServlet {

Session s;
int i=0;
static Logger log= Log.getLogger(UpdateTutor.class);

public UpdateTutor() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String tipo = request.getParameter("tipo");
    String seriale = request.getParameter("seriale");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    s = PersistanceSessionFactory.openSession("UpdateTutor"+seriale);
    log.infoServlet("Ricevo una richiesta di aggiornamento sul tutor "+seriale);

    if(seriale==null){
        out.write("No serial");
        s.close();
        return;
    }

    if(tipo==null){
        out.write(notificaAggiornamento(seriale));
        s.close();

    }else{
       out.write(updateAll(seriale));
       s.close();
    }
    return;
}
public String updateAll(String seriale) {
    log.infoServlet("Aggiornamento in corso..stampo lo stato attuale della centrale");
    String out = "";

    /*Addetti*/
    out+="<addetti val = \""+updateAddetti(seriale)+"\"/>\n";
            ..... 
            return out;
}

      public String updateAddetti(String seriale){
       .............
       if(a!=null){
            String den ="";
//Exception org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: This TransactionCoordinator has been closed
            Azienda az = (Azienda) s.get(Azienda.class, a.getId().getIdAzienda());



public class PersistanceSessionFactory {

private static String TAG = "PersistanceSessionFactory";
private static SessionFactory sf = null;
    .....
    public static Session openSession(String source){
    return sf.openSession();
}
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `Session` reference from `Class` level to `Method` level. Generally, there should't be any member which affects the operation of `doGet` / `doPost` methods in the `Servlet` Class level since *it will cause concurrency issues, when multiple requests have been received at the same time*. *Only one instance of Servlet exist per classloader to process all the requests*. Each request will be handled on its own thread. so, you should not close the session since it is in the Class level. Make it as a local variable of `doGet` method to avoid this error

Comment: Oh my god! I am a very careless idiot and you are a very kind person. That was the problem, now it works. thank you very much